# Matlab ode solver algebreic calculation

Tags: matlab, modeling, ode, algebraic-data-types

I have an ODE model in Matlab coded as a function.  I integrate the ODE's over time using ode15s. After the solver has finished, I calculate algebraically, a new variable that's a fraction of the sum of the other variables output by the model.

For example:

```
dA/dt = xxxxx
dB/dt = xxxxx
dC/dt = xxxxx
```

this gets integrated and returns an array of columns for dA,dB,dC.  From the output I calculate:

```
model_result = A/(A+B+C).
```

for the whole time course), and plot this vector of values vs time.

However, I also need to perform sensitivity analysis on the model, for which I've used the modified ODE15s on the [Mathworks repository](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1480-sensitivity-analysis-for-odes-and-daes).  I need to be able to set "model_result" above as the objective function for the sensitivity calculations.

I attempted to calculate model_result inside the function, and have it returned as another variable, but obviously this doesn't work as the integrator returns the integrated value, rather than the algebraically calculated value.

Is it possible to have algebraic values returned by an ODE solver in Matlab?

If not, does anybody have any idea how to perform this kind of sensitivity analysis?

thanks for any help. I'm quite new to modelling so apologies if I'm using all the wrong terms!

Comment: You're correct, the integration function should only be used to specify the ODEs. Trying to do other things with it may get you into trouble. Why can't you integrate your equations to solve for `A`, `B`, and `C` and calculate `model_result` from the output? It's not clear from your question. If you need to evaluate the solution at other time points use the single output form of `ode15s` that returns a struct in conjunction with [`deval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deval.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I can calculate model_result from the output. My problem is the sensitivity analysis.  I want to perform parametric sensitivity analysis on the model_output, but I can't as model_output is solved from the output of the integrator and sensitivities are calculated during the integration.  I can only perform sensitivity analysis on the variables of the model, and model_output isn't a variable. I somehow need to be able to make model_output a variable inside the model function, but I can't as it's calculated algebraically on the results of the integrator.

Comment: I just looked at `sens_sys`. First, the code is ten years old and doesn't even support current best practices with ODE suite function (e.g., specifying the integration function with a string). Second, are you sure that these functions actually do what you need? It looks like it is performing sensitivity analysis on system *parameters* `U` with respect to the state variables. You seem to want to look at the sensitivity of `model_result` with respect to ...? It's not very clear what you're doing/trying from your question without code.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain `d(model_result)/dU`, where `U` is a parameter? `sens_sys` will return `dA/dU`, `dB/dU`, and `dC/dU`. I think that you might be able calculate `d(model_result)/dU` in terms of these an your solutions `A`, `B`, and `C`: `(B*(dA/dU) - A*(dB/dU+dC/dU) + C*(dA/dU))/(A+B+C)^2`. But I don't know anything about sensitivity analysis, so don't trust me.

Comment: yes, I'm attempting to calculate the sensitivity of model_result with respect to changes in the system parameters, U. SENS_SYS calculates the sensitivity values for the state variables with respect to changes in parameters U. I need model_output to be one of the state variables so SENS_SYS includes it in the sensitivity calculation, but model_result is calculated *from* the state variables.